# Dynamic ORACLE SQL - How to convert a varchar2 variable to use as a column name in a select statement?

Tags: oracle, variables, varchar

I need to convert a varchar2(30) variable to use as a column name in a select statement or inside a sql function that is supposed to receive a column name.

How can I do this?

I'm trying to do some simple thing with dynamic sql like the following code, to solve this problem of varchar2 conversion but I cant get the expected result. It says "00900. 00000 - "invalid SQL statement" regarding the select statement in the query_string.

Does someone know where is the bug here?

```
 SET serveroutput ON;
 declare
 TYPE pointer IS REF CURSOR;
 yo pointer;
 var varchar2(20);
 query_string varchar2(200);
 num number;

 begin
 var := 'WORKERS'; --should be the column name!
 query_string := 'select'||var||'from MY_TABLE where MY_TABLE.ID = 2';
 OPEN yo FOR query_string;
 LOOP
 FETCH yo into num;
 EXIT WHEN yo%NOTFOUND;
 dbms_output.put_line(num);
 END LOOP;
 END ;
 /
```

Comment: Stop doing what you are doing, pick a book on relational databases, learn how to do relational databases, and then redesign your database so that you do not have any need to do anything of that sort.

Comment: what language? PL/SQL? check this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm

Comment: You need to have spaces between the words in your SQL statement. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> query_string := 'select'||var||'from MY_TABLE where MY_TABLE.ID = 2';

You are missing the required spaces between the words in the SQL statement. You SQL statement is parsed as:

`selectWORKERSfrom MY_TABLE where MY_TABLE.ID = 2`

Test yourself:

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2    var varchar2(20);
  3    query_string VARCHAR2(200);
  4  BEGIN
  5    var          := 'WORKERS'; --should be the column name!
  6    query_string := 'select'||var||'from MY_TABLE where MY_TABLE.ID = 2';
  7    dbms_output.put_line(query_string);
  8  END ;
  9  /
selectWORKERSfrom MY_TABLE where MY_TABLE.ID = 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

You need to have spaces between `SELECT <--> WORKERS <--> FROM`.

**Remember, always use DBMS_OUTPUT to test the dynamic sql before executing it.**

Anyway, see the following example,

```
SQL> variable yo REFCURSOR
SQL> DECLARE
  2      TYPE pointer IS REF CURSOR;
  3      yo pointer;
  4      var          VARCHAR2(20);
  5      query_string VARCHAR2(200);
  6      num          NUMBER;
  7    BEGIN
  8      var          := 'ENAME'; --should be the column name!
  9      query_string := 'select '||var||' from EMP where EMPNO = 7369';
 10      OPEN :yo FOR query_string;
 11  END ;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print yo

ENAME
----------
SMITH

SQL>
```

Comment: I thought the problem was solved but a new and related one arise. The code above works only for the column names which represents columns of 'number' type. For the column names that represents columns of Varchar type it gives me a error like: Error report:
ORA-01722: número inválido
ORA-06512: na linha 12
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action: